# How to make a Batch file for Del command but with verbose

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

Can someone help me make a Batch file that states what it is deleting in the command line?

I am a batch beginner and have not done this before.

I know that there is no `/V` command for `del` so I thought that batch might be my answer.

Could someone help?

Answer (score 2):

Write a file test.bat:

```
set delFileList=%*
FOR %%A IN (%delFileList%) DO (
    DEL %%A
    echo file %%A  deleted
)
```

Comment: This is a good first attempt, but it will not behave well if it attempts to delete a read only file. Also, it would be nice if it supported many of the standard DEL options.

Answer (score 2):

***WARNING -*** This solution does ***not*** prompt for confirmation if you attempt to delete an entire directory. Please be careful!

Below is LISTDEL.BAT that supports most of the normal DEL options.

I believe LISTDEL.BAT is very robust. The only limitation I can think of is it can fail if two processes that share the same %TEMP% folder attempt to run the utility at nearly the exact same time.

The code is extensively documented.

```
:::
:::LISTDEL.BAT [/?] [/F] [/S] [/A[[:]attributes]] Names
:::
:::  Deletes one or more files in much the same way as DEL, except each
:::  deleted file is listed.
:::
:::  Unlike DEL, LISTDEL never prompts for confirmation of global wildcard.
:::  Also, the /P option is not supported.
:::
:::    names         Specifies a list of one or more files or directories.
:::                  Wildcards may be used to delete multiple files. If a
:::                  directory is specified, all files within the directory
:::                  will be deleted.
:::
:::    /?            Display this help information
:::
:::    /F            Force deleting of read-only files.
:::
:::    /S            Delete specified files from all subdirectories.
:::
:::    /A            Selects files to delete based on attributes
:::    attributes    R  Read-only files            S  System files
:::                  H  Hidden files               A  Files ready for archiving
:::                  I  Not content indexed Files  L  Reparse Points
:::                  -  Prefix meaning not
:::
::: LISTDEL.BAT was written by Dave Benham and originally posted at:
::: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26680846/1012053
:::
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

:: Print help if /? used
echo(%*|findstr /ir "\</\?\>" >nul && (
  for /f "delims=: tokens=*" %%A in ('findstr /b ":::" "%~f0"') do echo(%%A
  exit /b 0
)

:: Fail if /P option used
echo(%*|findstr /ir "\</P\>" >nul && (
  echo Invalid switch - "P".>&2
  exit /b 0
)

:: Determine if /F option was used and save value
echo(%*|findstr /ir "\</F\>" >nul && set "force=/f" || set "force="

:: Determine length of the delete prompt that varies by language.
:: The English prompt is ", Delete (Y/N)? ", which results in -16.
set "tempFile=%temp%\showDel.tmp"
for %%F in ("%tempfile%") do >"%tempFile%" echo %%~fF
del /p "%tempFile%" <nul >"%tempFile%2"
for %%A in ("%tempFile%") do for %%B in ("%tempFile%2") do set /a "promptLen=%%~zA-%%~zB"
del "%tempFile%" "%tempFile%2"

:: Iterate list of files to be deleted via DEL /P /Q plus user supplied arguments.
:: No files are deleted because stdin is disabled - only a listing is produced.
:: Each listed file contains an unwanted delete prompt at the end.
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('del /p /q %* ^<nul') do (

  %= Get the full path to the file by stripping off the trailing delete prompt =%
  %= Toggle delayed expansion on and off to protect ! that may be in the path  =%
  set "file=%%F"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "file=!file:~0,%promptLen%!"

  %= Attempt to delete the file and pipe any error message to FINDSTR.    =%
  %= Redirect FINDSTR output (any found error message) back to stderr.    =%
  %= If error message found, then inform what file coudn't be deleted,    =%
  %= else list the deleted file.                                          =%
  %= File attribute restrictions have already been applied in outer loop, =%
  %= so DEL /A option is used to disregard file attributes.               =%
  del %force% /a "!file!" 2>&1 >nul | findstr . >&2 && >&2 echo Unable to delete !file!||echo !file!
  endlocal
)
exit /b 0
```

Comment: EDIT - Add HELP facility, and dissallow /P option.